# Search for all documents that match each ID of an array in mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of user IDs called `senders`.

```
senders = [ '5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1', '5938ecc505335007317bf1ce' ]
```

In my MongoDB collection, I have multiple documents that contain each of these IDs.  Each document has this structure:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5938e247897daa05218bb33c"
    },
    "message": "Hi Sara!",
    "from": "Joe",
    "to": "Sara",
    "from_user_id": "5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1",
    "to_user_id": "5934fe100b557624207db665",
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2017-06-08T05:36:07.752Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

The field, `from_user_id`, in each document matches one of the IDs in my `senders` array.

How do I loop through `senders`, and find the corresponding documents (assuming there is more than one document)?

**Here's what I've tried:**

I can do this with a single ID:

```
Message.find({ from_user_id: senders[0]}, (err, msg) => {console.log(msg)})
```

where `senders[0] = 5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1`

This results in finding two documents that match this user ID:

```
[ { _id: 5938e247897daa05218bb33c,
    message: 'Hi Sara!',
    from: 'Joe',
    to: 'Sara',
    from_user_id: '5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1',
    to_user_id: '5934fe100b557624207db665',
    created_at: 2017-06-08T05:36:07.752Z,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5938e42c967cc106d8d207b9,
    message: 'Hi again.',
    from: 'Joe',
    to: 'Sara',
    from_user_id: '5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1',
    to_user_id: '5934fe100b557624207db665',
    created_at: 2017-06-08T05:44:12.630Z,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

I tried `map()`ing over the `senders` array first, then doing `.find()`, like so:

```
var all_messages = []
senders.map((sender) => {
 Message.find({ from_user_id: sender}, (err, msg) => {
  all_messages.push(msg)
 })
})
```

But the resulting array, `all_messages`, is not available outside of `.map()`.  This same problem exists when I use `senders.forEach()`, and a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/). No need to loop, it takes a list. `.find({ "from_user_id": { "$in": senders } }).exec(`

Comment: Ok, so that works, but it returns a single array.  Is there a way to return an array of arrays?
`array_1 = Message.find({ from_user_id: senders[0]}, (err, msg) => {console.log(msg)})`
`array_2 = Message.find({ from_user_id: senders[1]}, (err, msg) => {console.log(msg)})`
`// …`
`main_array = [array_1, array_2, …]`
This way, each element in `main_array` contains all messages sent by a single user (contained within an array)